# Adding Informix JDBC to Jasper Server

Tags: apache, tomcat, jdbc, informix, jasperserver

i have installed Jasper Server on my local. I need to generate a report which will extract data from Informix DB. Therefore a JDBC for it is needed (duh). I found the JDBC file for informix called ifxjdbc.jar and i copy it to "/apache-tomcat/lib". Restarted the server. Then when i want to create a new data source, the dropdown list doesn't show my JDBC driver that i just added.

I even tried copying the JDBC file to "/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro/lib" then restart the server but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You should install JDBC driver which is available on IBM pages. It contains more jar files than just only `ifxjdbc.jar`. In my environment I copied: `ifxjdbc.jar`, `ifxjdbcx.jar`, `ifxlang.jar`, `ifxlsupp.jar`, `ifxsqlj.jar` and `ifxtools.jar`.

I think that you should run simple Java/Jython program that tries to connect to your database. If it will work then you are sure you have complete environment.

Comment: i have downloaded all the files and copied all of it to the lib directory. but still not working.

Comment: as 'not working' i mean the driver still not showing up on the dropdown list